# Save data in database after tableView data changed

Tags: c++, database, qt, qtableview

I am showing data from an Sqlite database in a `QStandardItemModel` in the tableView so that the user can edit it. I want to save these changes back to my database now, once the user presses "Save" or tries to exit with unsaved changes (to give a promt, in such a case).

What could be the best way to do this? I was thinking of running update queries. But is there a way that I run the queries only on those rows which have been modified by the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `QSqlTableModel` to show a table contents in a `QTableView` :

```
QSqlTableModel * model = new QSqlTableModel(this,db);
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
model->setTable( "someTable" );
model->select();

ui->tableView->setModel( model );
```

For saving or cancelling changes you can begin a tranaction and commit or rollback at the end. Starting a transaction is like :

```
model->database().transaction();
```

Code for your save button:

```
if(model->submitAll())
    model->database().commit();
else
    model->database().rollback();
```

Code for your cancel button:

```
model->revertAll();
model->database().rollback();
```

Comment: Can this be used even when my TableView is showing a result of a join statement ?

Comment: In that case you should use `QSqlRelationalTableModel` for your contents. That case is similar to the answer.

Comment: @Nejat and jm. : thank you very much, I got stuck on this point in my project and it took my days to figure out that I had forgotten model->database().transaction(); and model->database().commit(); . Your post really helped me

Answer (score 0):

You should use the built-in `QSqlTableModel` class. It provides an editable data model and can  automatically save changes.